# Add button to list cell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I add a button to my `List` cell?

```
var body: some View{
    List {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Hello, World!")
            }, label: {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            })
            Text("Something irrelevant")
        }
    }
}
```

The above prints `Hello, World!` when I tap `Hello, World!`, but also when I tap `Something irrelevant`. I only want it to happen when tapping the button, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SwiftUI, when you tap a cell in a list, the `action` parameter of each child button is called. If this is not the behaviour you want, you need to configure the `tapAction` property of the button, while leaving the `action` parameter blank.

In this case, your code would like this:

```
 var body: some View{
        List {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {

                }, label: {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }).tapAction {
                    print("Hello, World!")
                }
                Text("Something irrelevant")
            }
        }
    }
```